# How to calculate the AVG() in MYSql of each row

Tags: mysql, average

I have a MYSQL users Table that looks like this:

```
NAME /  Q1  /   Q2   /  Q3   /   Q4  /  AVG
john     3      4        2        5
```

Where Q's are grades for each criteria.

I'd like to know how to insert in each AVG column, the average of q1,q2,q3,q4.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: The design is actually for something else, but the answers solved my problem properly.
However the design could be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them together and divide them by four.

```
SELECT name,
       q1,
       q2,
       q3,
       q4,
       (q1 + q2 + q3 + q4) / 4 avg
       FROM users;
```

Or change the design and rather have a table for the grades looking like:

```
 userid | period | grade
--------+--------+-------
 1      | q1     | 3
 1      | q2     | 4
 1      | q3     | 2
 1      | q4     | 5
```

Then you can use aggregation.

```
SELECT avg(grade)
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is simple maths

```
UPDATE `table` SET `AVG` = (Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4)/4
```